# Showing that this function is unbounded on every open interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $A = (0,\infty)$ and $f : A \to \Bbb{R}$ be defined as
>
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in A \cap (\Bbb{R}-\Bbb{Q}) \\ n, & x = \frac{m}{n} \in A \cap \Bbb{Q}  \end{cases},$$
>
> where $gcd(m,n)=1$. Prove that $f$ is unbounded on every open interval in $A$.

Taking an arbitrary interval $(a,b)$, and
considering a large positive number, $M>0.$

We can say that there exists, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that, $n>M.$ (By the archimedian property)

Now, $a+\frac{1}{n}$ is an element of $(a,b).$
Therefore, $f(a+ \frac{1}{n}) = f(\frac{na+1}{n}) = n.$
($n$ and $na+1$ are co-prime)

Hence, for any arbitrary large number $M$, there exists an element $(a+\frac{1}{n})$ such that

$$f(a+\frac{1}{n}) = n > M$$

So, $f(x)$ is unbounded on any open interval in $A.$

...

I would really appreciate it if you could go over this proof, and tell me how to improve it! Thank you.

Comment: If $a$ is irrational, so is $a+\frac{1}{n}$, then $f(a + \frac{1}{n})=0$.

Comment: Also, even if $a$ is rational, $na+1$ may be is not an integer, so make no sense talking about $n$ and $na+1$ being coprime.

Comment: Since rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence for any open interval $I=(a,b)\subseteq A$ we have there exist rational number $p/q\in I$. Also for $n$ large enough $p/q +1/n= \frac{pn+q}{nq}\in I$

Comment: @jjagmath ah i see. I think then, like Akash suggested, I should work with a rational number i pick from inside the interval.

Comment: For rational given $x_n=m/n$ written irreductibly. You can take the sequence define $x'_p=m/(pn)$ where $p$ take values from  $p_0$ which is  the smallest prime such that $gcd(m,p_0)=1$. It follows that $f(x_p)=pn$ which diverges as wanted.

Comment: Sorry to say, but ratio $\frac{pn+q}{nq}$ in my trick does not works! because if gcd(p,q)=1 then gcd(pn+q, nq) need not be 1. For example, take $p=5, q=7$ and $n=7$ then, $gcd(pn+q,nq)=7≠1$. So you need consider some other ratio.

Comment: You can take for example $2^n$, if $1/2^n<b-a$ then there exists $p\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\left\lbrace\frac{p}{2^{n+1}},\frac{p+1}{2^{n+1}}\right\rbrace\subset(a,b)$ then $gcd(p,2^{n+1})=1$ or $gcd(p+1,2^{n+1})=1$